# Combination of cells

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current

> There are m*n identical cells of emf E and internal resistance r connected in parallel rows. This combination of cells is connected across an external resistance R. For what arrangement of the cells will the current through R be maximum?

I don't understand when the current will be maximum, i.e.: when the number of resistors in each row is same, or if the number of resistors in each row is different, or if there is any other specific arrangement.
.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Current will be at its maximum when $\frac{n}{m}=\frac{R}{r}$ (i.e., when the total internal resistance is equal to the external resistance).

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) You might want to see [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for advice on typesetting formulas :)

Answer (score -1):

Put 1 cell in each row. In other words, put all the cells parallel to each other. This way all the currents from individual cells add up and you have the least internal resistance of the cells, giving you the largest current through your external resistor.

Answer (score -2):

The current through the resistor R will be a maximum when the potential difference across that resistor is a maximum. For typical passive resistors, more potential difference means more current.

You job is to find the arrangement of cells that would cause the greatest potential difference across the external resistor.